# Water + metal + fan = convection cooling?

Tags: temperature, radiation, convection

I'm playing around with the notion of a swamp fan, but I live in a humid climate and have no interest in putting more humidity in my bedroom.

Supposing I submerged a rod of metal into a mostly sealed bucket of cold water and ice, and then put a fan in front of it, would this cool the air without adding too much humidity?

[image]

EDIT>>>>

As discussed in the comments, the water in this case, would be coming from an underground well, and therefore already be cool.

It occurred to me that the water could be pumped into plastic fins instead, with the fan blowing air behind. The warm water could be gradually pumped out.

See image

[image]

In terms of the physics here, would this concept work well enough to be significant? I assume there would be no humidity added to the air, given the water would be contained in plastic?

Comment: Are you trying to create a home-made dehumidifier?

Comment: Passive cooling, really.

Comment: The fact that a fan consumes energy but doesn't actually reduce the temperature of a space is a splinter in my mind.

Comment: Then you want multiple thin, long metal fins, not a single rod...

Comment: Yeah, I had been thinking that.

Comment: Or find a way to cool the blades directly, without having the motor touch the water somehow

Comment: Condensing water takes a lot of energy, so once the device gets going, it will thaw the ice very quickly. At the end of the day... you need to install a suitable AC unit with dehumidifier, if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "motor touch the water"?  The energy consuming part of this design will be cooling the water, unless you bury the sealed bucket several feet underground.  Then you can take advantage of the roughly constant temperature of Earth's crust.

Comment: I was thinking well water is pretty cold. Dunno what the energy use of pump is, by comparison to a conventional AC unit.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I meant like, if the blades were indirectly attached to the cold metal. Or if most of the fan was submerged.

Comment: What blades and what metal?

Comment: Blades of the fan, metal being the metal rod. I'll add a picture.

Comment: Actually, never mind, I suppose the blades of the fan are barely in contact with the base.

Comment: If you can pump the well water to your room, an old car radiator with a fan would work. See  http://www.fieldlines.com/index.php?topic=143881.0  other radiator types would be suitable as well.

Comment: @Previous So it would essentially be doing the reverse of what goes on in a car by blowing out the cold instead of the heat, and then cycling out?

Comment: @Previous My other concern is the energy consumption in the water pump, which I assume would have to run fairly consistently? Is it possible to say, bring the water up into an insulated container that is elevated, and use some hydraulic tubing and gravity to pump it through?